# Solving $x^3+x-\epsilon = 0$ with iteration

Tags: perturbation-theory

I'm trying to solve $x^3+x-\epsilon = 0$ using the iteration method. From the equation, I have $x_{n+1} = (\epsilon-x_n)^{1/3}$. My question is how can I choose a reasonable $x_0$? When $\epsilon = 0$, the 3 roots of the equation are $0, i $ and $-i$. But I don't think any of them should be used as an initial guess.

**Update:**

As suggested in the answers, when $\epsilon$ is positive and approaches $0$, the real root of this function also approaches $0$. If we set $x_0 = 0$, then $x_1 = \epsilon^{1/3}$, $x_2 = (\epsilon-\epsilon^{1/3})^{1/3}$, etc. As $\epsilon\rightarrow0^+$, $x\rightarrow0$. It looks like $x$ becomes a function of $\epsilon$. How do we find the asymptotic expansion of this root? For the imaginary roots, should I repeat similar procedures?

Comment: That is not a quadratic equation.

Comment: $x$ does become a function of $\epsilon$, but what happens with the iteration you proposed is a little bit more subtle than you seem to think it is. Try it for a concrete value of $\epsilon$ like $0.01$.

Answer (score 3):

For the real root, the simplest way is to write
$$x=\sum_{n=1}^p a_n\, \epsilon^n$$ Expand it and cancel coefficients.

You should get
$$x=\epsilon -\epsilon ^3+3 \epsilon ^5+\cdots$$

If you contiue for more terms and identify the patterns
$$x=\sum_{n=1}^p (-1)^{n+1}\binom{3 (n-1)}{n-1}\frac {\epsilon^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$$ If $p\to \infty$
$$x=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3}
   }{2} \epsilon\right)\right)$$ which is the exact solution for any value of $\epsilon$.

You could have found it using the [hyperbolic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root) for one real root in cubic equations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why can we write $x$ as a sum of $a_n\epsilon^p$?

Comment: You have at least one notational error in the original introduction of the sum.

Comment: @Ian. Sory, but I do not see where. Could you explain ? Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The exponent doesn't depend on $n$ in the original introduction.

Comment: @Ian. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the exact roots of the unperturbed equation as initial guesses, and if your iteration is selected appropriately then you will have convergence to the corresponding root of the perturbed equation for small enough $\epsilon$.

In fact, starting with the solutions to the unperturbed problem is the normal thing to do in a "regular" perturbation problem like this (where the number of solutions is the same when $\epsilon=0$ as otherwise). Problems where that can't be done are called "singular".

It's worth trying the iteration that you proposed especially for $x_0=0$; something interesting happens.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just updated my question. Am I on the right track for $x_0=0$? Should I repeat similar procedures for the imaginary roots?

Comment: @IGY The punchline of what I have been pointing out is that the root near $0$ is an *unstable* fixed point of the iteration you proposed, so you will generally not get convergence to it.

Comment: Thanks so much, I tried the value, and indeed x is unstable in each iteration. Does this mean I should consider a complex initial guess? (as the other two roots are also complex)

Comment: @IGY For an unstable fixed point, just about every point will not converge to the fixed point (sometimes more than just the fixed point itself can coincidentally land there). You need a different iteration entirely.

Comment: By 'different iteration', so you mean a new choice of $x_0$, or a different iteration formula?

Comment: @IGY A different iteration formula.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x^3+x-\epsilon$ is clearly an increasing function. So, the equation $f(x)=0$ has one real root. Assuming $\epsilon>0$, this root must be positive, since $f(0)=-\epsilon<0$.

Due to the intermediate value theorem, there is an integer $N\geq 0$ such that this root is in the interval $(N,N+1)$ where $f(N)<0$ but $f(N+1)>0$. Choose the starting point of your fixed point iteration as $x_0=N+1.$

I started with $x_0=3$ for $x^3+x-20=0$ and $x_5=x_6=...$ according to WA: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%2820-2.5917%29%5E%281%2F3%29

But of course the root is not 2.5917. At this point it is better to choose a new initial. Maybe $x_0=2.59171$.

Comment: Actually the $N$ in question is $0$, not $>0$, unless $\epsilon$ is at least $2$. You also still won't find it with OP's iteration as you suggest because it is unstable. What you actually get is oscillatory dynamics, ping-ponging between a neighborhood of $1$ and a neighborhood of $-1$.

Comment: I missed $N\geq 0$.